# indivudually sorting each number inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I made the code underneath to sort my array and make a string filled with the respective users leaderboard.

the "points" variable looks like this

```
points: {
  '204255221017214977': 3,
  '208993609255485441': 5,
  '382197942762602496': 4,
  '664606841409634324': 5,
  '779857709155090432': 4,
  '381084508276916225': 5,
  '794200859612545075': 4,
  '155149108183695360': 4,
  '438978127973318656': 3,
  '304028235082104843': 2,
  '174548757151481856': 1
}
```

I was wondering if there is a much easier way to sort and put together the string like I did underneath with much easier code. Cuz I'll be honest this looks and feels aweful.

example endresult:

```
:first_place: @Excanator had 5 points
:first_place: @zerow had 5 points
:first_place: @AnimeHotOwO had 5 points

:second_place: @christmas beans had 4 points
:second_place: @ExcavatorGames had 4 points
:second_place: @Dyno had 4 points
:second_place: @LogiBot Premium had 4 points

:third_place: @Restarter v3 had 3 points
:third_place: @YAGPDB.xyz had 3 points

@aNt had 2 points
@Kaori had 1 point
```

```
const sorted = Object.keys(points).sort((a, b) => {
    return points[b] - points[a]
})

var results = `\n`

var firstPlace = points[sorted[0]]
var secondPlace = null
var thirdPlace = null
var leftover = null

for(const key of sorted) {
    var amount = points[key]
    if(leftover){
        results += `<@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
    } else if(thirdPlace) {
        if(thirdPlace === amount) {
            results += `:third_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
        } else {
            results += `\n`
            results += `<@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
            leftover = amount
        }
    } else if(secondPlace) {
        if(secondPlace === amount) {
            results += `:second_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
        } else {
            results += `\n`
            results += `:third_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
            thirdPlace = amount
        }
    } else if(firstPlace) {
        if(firstPlace === amount) {
            results += `:first_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
        } else {
            results += `\n`
            results += `:second_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
            secondPlace = amount
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already included an example endresult if that's what you mean?

Comment: Would you share the input that should end-up looking like the resulting string above?

Comment: edited the points variable the way it is inputted

Comment: Now, your data is missing key->username mapping

Comment: this is with the discordapi so when you do `<@${key}>` it'll automaticly make it into the user

Comment: DRY: Write a function that formats all the messages, since they follow the same pattern.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: I see. my bad I'll go there right now! thank you